# Adding a variable to each object in a list of model objects

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have the following model classes:

```
class Collection(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  text_keys = db.ListProperty(db.Key)

class Text(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  content = db.StringProperty()
```

and I'm trying to do the following:

```
class Collections(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    collections = model.Collection.all() # works fine

    for c in collections:
      c.number_of_texts = len(c.text_keys) # does not work

    template_values = {
      'collections': collections,
    }
```

I'm certainly no python-expert, but shouldn't this work?

UPDATE:

By does not work i mean that the variable number_of_texts is not added to the model object.

In my django-template, the following code generates nothing, except for the collection name:

```
{% for c in collections %}
<p>{{c.name}}, number of texts: {{c.number_of_texts}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

SOLUTION:

Thanks to RocketDonkey for pointing out that this can be done in a more elgant fashion using django formatting:

```
{% for c in collections %}
<p>{{c.name}}, number of texts: {{c.text_keys|length}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

or by passing a separate dictionary with the names and lenghts to the template, if a similar problem with no good formatting solution should occur.

Comment: I realize that it might be better to have a variable in the Collection class that counts the number of associated texts, but every now and then I need to link a new variable (like the number_of_texts in this case) to each model object so it can be used inside a django-template for-loop.

Comment: "# does no work" ... What do you mean by that?  Is there an exception thrown?  If so, can you post the traceback?  If there is no excepion, what's not working?

Comment: I'm sorry, poorly documented by me. By does not work I mean that it simply does not add a variable numberoftexts to each object in collections,
eg. The following template generates nothing
{% for c in collections %}
<p>{{c.number_of_texts}}</p>{% endfor %}

Comment: Still, if you add an attribute to an object and then pass that object to the template, it *should* work.  So it's still mysterious that it doesn't.  Maybe you had a typo in your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that you are trying to write to the `number_of_texts` property of the `Collection` model (which does not exist :) ). If you just need to get the number of items in that list element, you'll need to store it in a separate variable not tied to `c`:

```
for c in collections:
  number_of_texts = len(c.text_keys)
```

In order to add the length of the list to your document (assuming you don't need it anywhere else), try using the `length` function in your template:

```
{% for c in collections %}
    <p>{{c.name}}, number of texts: {{c.text_keys|length}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This may not work depending on your templating engine (I have only used one so I'm far from an expert), but it will hopefully get you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was thinking that I could expand the objects with an extra property just for the purpose of generating the html-page, but this is perhaps not possible?
I can manage storing it in a separate variable (eg. a list of numbers), but then I run into trouble when trying to link the number of texts to the right collection name in the django-template

Comment: @user1612947 Gotcha, your expanded post above makes sense. Amending my answer now.

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I tend to run into this problem of adding some quick calculated property to an object after pulling it from the datastore quite often, without necessarily feeling the need to store it permanently.

Comment: @user1612947 Yeah, totally makes sense. If the above method doesn't work, you could also try creating a separate dictionary that was keyed by `Collection.name`, with the values being the length of `text_keys`. You could then pass that dictionary to the template along with `collections` and then use it to lookup the length of whatever `c.name` you're iterating on (haven't ever tried that, so take it with a grain of salt).

Comment: Thank you for an elegant solution! It worked great. I'll try the dictionary as well, sounds like a reasonable solution for slightly more complex cases.

Comment: @user1612947 Awesome, glad it works! Depending on the type of property, I would look into the functions of Django itself (which is what was used here, although I imagine it is similar with others). If they are relatively simple (and probably even if they are a bit more complicated), I imagine there is a way to generate it there without having to do it in your app script. Otherwise, passing in a second dictionary with the attributes you want may be a (clunkier) solution.